# Assign a tag to an object in a unity via code permanently

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a subway simulator
I made a lot of empty blocks, they all have the `Uncreated` tag by default and they do not have a name, when you click on any of them, a window appears, if the station is with the `Uncreated` tag, then the station creation window, if with the `Created` tag , then the edit window. The `Created` tag is assigned via the script below

I want the `StationBox` to always have the `Created` tag after pressing a button, but it goes back to the previous value when the game is restarted, how can I solve this?

I would like to make a universal script for all stations

```
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class AddStation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField Input;
    public Text StationName;
    public GameObject Button;
    public GameObject CreateStation;
    public GameObject StationBox;

    public void OnMouseDown(){
        if (Input.text != ""){
            CreateStation.SetActive(false);
            StationName.text = Input.text.ToString();
            StationBox.tag = "Created";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "game is restarted", are you referring to pressing the play button in the editor or reloading the current scene at runtime?

Comment: I mean button in unity editor

Comment: How are you keeping the stations in the scene between plays?

Comment: I have not started doing this yet, but just realized that there will be the same problem

Comment: It sounds like the station is already in the scene before pressing play.  If so, why not set the tag in the scene, outside of play mode?

Comment: There are stations in the scene, but they have the "Uncreated" tag and they are unnamed, if I set the "Created" tag in advance, then when I click on it, I will open the station editing window, not the creation window

Comment: There seems to be a great deal of information left out of your post.  Please update your question with enough information for us to recreate your issue.  Please include the steps you take when running your project, actions taken, and results.  Also, describe how your scene is setup prior to pressing play.

Comment: I added the description of the question